# How do I use the NSString draw functionality to create a UIImage from text and combine this image with another UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have  NSString draw functionality to create a UIImage from text  and combine this image with another UIImage and also movable UIImage.now i want to combine this Two UIImage together into a single UIImage.

Comment: Please ask your question properly. What have you tried, what's working, what's not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text
{
    // set the font type and size
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
    CGSize size  = [text sizeWithFont:font];

    // check if UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is available (iOS is 4.0+)
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0.0);
    else
        // iOS is < 4.0
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    // optional: add a shadow, to avoid clipping the shadow you should make the context size bigger
    //
    // CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0), 5.0, [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]);

    // draw in context, you can use also drawInRect:withFont:
    [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];

    // transfer image
    UIImage *Image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return Image;
}
```

Here i got the idea for changing a text into an image.

Comment: Now i want to combine this image with another UIimage .How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext and related functions this lets you create a bitmap image from and drawing. You can can draw your text and anything else you want to create a new bitmap.